# Erro de Caractereres especiais JS, servidor linux

Tags: javascript, html, linux, apache, visual-studio-code

Upei meu Projeto no Servidor Linux e Os textos gerados dentro do Arquivo Java script Aparecem assim:

const numeros = [
{ nome: "Belo", departamento: "MKT", setor: "SecretÃ¡rias ", numero: "1111" },
{ nome: "MÃ©lia", departamento: "MKT", setor: "SecretÃ¡rias ", numero: "1111" },
{ nome: "Pedro", departamento: "MKT", setor: "HabitaÃ§Ã£o", numero: "1111" },
{ nome: "Pedro", departamento: "MKT", setor: "HabitaÃ§Ã£o", numero: "1111" },
];

//Restante do Codigo

function limparResultados() {
const resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
resultado.innerHTML = ''; // Limpar o conteÃºdo do resultado
}

Porém os Textos Que estão dentro do Arquivo HTML estão normais, ja utilizo o meta charset UTF-8, é só os textos que estão dentro do arquivo JS que estão com erro.

Comment: Não duplique perguntas, portanto os comentários foram desativado aqui para que continue na [pergunta original](/q/587311/3635)